# Shell redirection - follow name, not a descriptor

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection

I have a shell script that is run in the background and the only thing it does is run 1 command, STDOUT of which is being appended to a file.

```bsh
my_blocking_command >> my_file
```

I want to stop the number of lines growing too much, so I run:

```
[ "$(cat my_file)" -ge 30 ] && tail -n20 my_file | sponge my_file
```

The problem arises when the file is overwritten - the file descriptor doesn't point to current `my_file` anymore - `my_blocking_command` writes to a file descriptor that doesn't point to the file I want it to.

How can I make sure, that everything a command outputs is always redirected to `my_file`, even if it's overwritten? (follow the name, instead of file descriptor, like `tail --follow=name`)

Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: If you're already using `tail` (and not using `tail -f`), why is `sponge` even coming into play for 20 lines of output?

Comment: `tail -f` would follow the file changes - I want to get last lines of the current file and have them be the only lines left in the file. `sponge` is needed as to not to overwrite the file before tail can read it.

Comment: It appears you are reinventing `logrotate` ? particularly its copytruncate option ?

Comment: `copytruncate` option does reset the file to bytes. And if I remember correctly, `logrotate` only does that when size gets over threshold or after file gets too old - not based on number of lines.

Now that you mentioned it, I rememebered checking before implementing this that with normal, not-appending redirection, the file gets truncated before writing, thus leaving orifinal FD untouched. so I went for:
`{ content="$(tail -n20 my_file)"; cat - > my_file <<<"${content}"; }`
Probably not the best solution - but a good enough and works for me!

Comment: I see. You might then redirect your command’s output to `logger` then ? and set a specific rule in `syslogd` for such output. The thing is, I’m afraid that what you’re asking is not allowed at all on Unix systems, by design. Conventionally it is always a program’s task to close-and-reopen long-standing file-descriptors. If your command does not do that and you can’t modify it to do so then the other option is to fill that gap via a helper program that receives your command’s output (a simple pipe) and properly handles your `my_file` on behalf of your command

Comment: (PS: tag me if you want me to be notified of your replies to my comments)

Comment: @LL3 The program isn't editable, but both bash scripts are - so if it's possible, I could just change the first one.
Unfortunately when using `logger` I'd then have to exctract it from syslog.
This is a specific case where I need the file to have roughly the given amount of lines.
As I mentioned, I've decided to do it 2-stepped like this:
`[ "$(wc -l my_file)" -ge 30 ] && { content="$(tail -n20 my_file)"; /usr/bin/printf '\%s\n' "${content}" > my_file ; }` and it works great in a cron job!
It isn't perfect, but it gets the job done - good enough for this "quick" hack.